# Backup of AWS instance store data

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have some data on instance storage volume(not root device).I want to take backup of this data as stopping the instance will make data unavailable.
What step should i follow to take the back of instance storage

Answer (score 0):

If you have data you need to save, keeping it on an ephemeral volume is not the right solution. 
What you want to do is the following:

- Create an EBS volume with a suitable size (AWS Managament Console)
- Attach the EBS volume to the instance (AWS Managament Console)
- Create a filesystem on the volume (something like mkfs.ext3 ) in Linux)
- Mount the volume
- Copy the data from the original instance volume to the new EBS volume (something like cp -r in Linux)

A similar process can be done with Windows, only that you need the disk manager to initialize the new disk and to format it

Once the data is on an EBS volume it is persistent, you may want to consider backing that volume if the data is important.